# Does one use a hyphen in between 'other' and 'hand' when saying "on the other hand"?

Tags: hyphenation

When I was typing this sentence "And on the other hand, some user actions don't trigger the same response." my spell checker mentioned that I might put a hyphen between 'other' and 'hand' and use 'other-hand'.

So in this sentence is a hyphen placed between 'other' and 'hand'?

Comment: One minor point in addition to psmears' answer: a [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) is not the same as a hyphen.

Comment: That's good to know, what's the difference?

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen

Comment: ... or just follow that link in my comment. (^_^)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, no hyphen is needed (and indeed it would be wrong to put one in this case). You are right to doubt your spell-checker :-)

Comment: Agreed. I imagine that the spell-checker's programmer was thinking of something like "off-hand", which would be hyphenated.