# When to use -, – and —?

Tags: hyphenation, dashes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen)

This is about hyphens (-), en-dashes (–) and em-dashes (—).

When to use which one? To be honest, I always use em-dashes unless I join words with a hyphen, but I never use an en-dash.

Comment: Exact Duplicate of: [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen)

Comment: @iamsid I'm sorry. It didn't show up in the 'related' box when I typed the title. I don't have enough rep yet to close this. :(

Comment: @iamsid, no I'm a Time Machine. :)

Comment: Machine: No need to apologize! We're only human. :)

Answer (score 7):

Hyphens are used in compound modifiers.

- a well-trained professional
- over-the-counter drugs

En dashes are used in place of "to" to connect numbers or words.

- The London–Amsterdam flight is delayed.
- The meeting is from 3:00–4:30 p.m.

Em dashes help set off amplifying or explanatory statements.

- The vampire—it had been awake half the night—flew out of its coffin.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.