# What is the difference between `-` and `--`

Tags: differences, punctuation, hyphenation, dashes, orthography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen)

Is there any difference between:

`-`

and

`--` or in some cases, a long dash

I have seen these two used lots of places but I really don't know the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The good people at Microsoft Word may have confused authors by setting up auto-correct to replace two sequential dashes with a single em (longer) dash. The intent is to be helpful because the em dash can be quite useful, but does not appear on standard keyboards; but the effect is to confuse many people who fail to spot the non-obvious difference between the short and long dashes.

Stylistically, I believe the convention for using an em dash is to let the writer signal that the thought after the dash is a kind of temporary interruption to the flow of the sentence and its paragraph.