# May en-dashes be used in sports scores?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, dashes, writing-style

The accepted answer to the authoritative question [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen) currently has this to say regarding the *en-dash*:

> An en-dash is use to connect values in a range or that are related. Saying "in years 1939–1945" or **"New York beat Los Angeles 98–95"** are both examples where an en-dash should be used (as I did explicitly in the examples). A good rule of from here is when you're expressing a "to" relationship.

The portion that I have bolded above is not a usage I had seen before. I was under the impression that the *en-dash* should only be used in the case of a range. In the above, two distinct scores are being described, not a range that includes the values "96" and "97".

The *"rule of from"* [sic?] presented above allows its usage in that case *("98 to 95")* but is broader than I believe in. Taken to the absurd, this might suggest that I could rewrite *"just between us, man-to-man"* as *"just between us, man–man"*. :p

What say you: must an *en-dash* be used only for a range of values, or may it be used more permissively?

Answer (score 2):

It does look rather awkward to me, but there's nothing wrong with it. An en dash is typically used for ranges, but it can also be used for [relationships and connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Relationships_and_connections) as in sports scores and votes, though these usages are somewhat contested, or just plain falling out of favour.

Typographywise, I think I would prefer to use a [figure dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Figure_dash) if it's available. It usually isn't, though, and in most fonts, the en dash is actually a better substitute for the figure dash than the hyphen is, so you should just use whatever works, I guess.