# Does "cost-benefit ratio" use a hyphen or an en-dash?

Tags: hyphenation, dashes

Should I write "cost-benefit" (hyphen) or "cost–benefit" (en dash), and why?

Comment: duplicate? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen

Comment: @z7sg: I'm not sure. The answer to that question only covers en dashes for numbers ("'in years 1939–1945' or 'New York beat Los Angeles 98–95'"), but not for words (e.g. *mother–daughter relationship* or *Paris–London flight*).

Comment: @z7sg, to my reading, that thread doesn't explicitly answer this question -- its answers could argue for either form.

Comment: @RegDwight Perhaps the answer isn't clear enough but it does say: 'A hyphen is used to join words in a compound construction' That's the answer imo, and as for *why* I'm not sure how you could answer that.

Comment: OK in this case I agree it's a good question. :) The inconsistency of the wikipedia entry for cost-benefit analysis is evidence of that.

Comment: @pilcrow: +1 just for your username :-)

Comment: The accepted answer for the other question clearly states that hyphens are used for joining "words in a compound construction." It seems it covers also the _cost-benefit_ case.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, yes.  However, I think there's an argument to be made that "cost/benefit" is *not* a simple compound; instead, the *relation* of "cost" to "benefit" is what's important in this construction.  [Jon Purdy's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21970/does-cost-benefit-ratio-use-a-hyphen-or-an-en-dash/21988#21988) is the only one so far that considers this.

Comment: @pilcrow The question is about writing _cost-benefit_, or _cost–benefit_. Both the answer given here, and the answer given in the other question says the same thing: When joining terms, you should use a hyphen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formally, hyphens are for *joining* terms, and en dashes are for *ranges* and *distinctions*. En dashes have a secondary application joining terms that are *already* hyphenated or contain spaces, but that doesn't apply here. In this situation I would use an en dash or a slash. Of course, if you do write it with a hyphen, nobody is going to be confused.

Technically, *cost–benefit analysis* can be interpreted as either *[cost–benefit] analysis*—an analysis of costs versus benefits—or *cost–[benefit analysis]*—costs versus an analysis of benefits. Luckily, the latter doesn't make any sense and would really only arise from deliberate pedantic misinterpretation.

Comment: can you expand on this a bit?  Are you saying you see "cost&ndash;benefit" as a _range_ or a _distinction_?

Comment: @pilcrow: *cost–benefit* is a distinction; *3–4* is a range. Both use en dashes.

Comment: I wouldn't have phrased it as a distinction, but I see what you're saying.

Comment: I don't know why you were anonymously downvoted, Jon.  +1 from me.

Answer (score 9):

Nobody here has nailed it. Here's the answer:

In the construction "Pre–Civil War," the en-dash is correct because it modifies both "civil" and "war." What the OP is wondering is whether this idea carries over to "cost-benefit ratio" and of course you can see that it doesn't, because "benefit ratio" is not a compound term.

This is a very arcane bit of typesetting knowledge, and you'll see it observed only in the highest-end publications like *New York Review of Books* and *The Economist.*

Comment: Thank you, Cerberus. It's taking me a very long time to master the formatting skills needed to do the kind of thing you just did.

Comment: @TheRaven: I am using an Autohotkey script to type accents quickly and without effort. I type `--qq` for an n-dash and `--xx` for an m-dash. It appears immediately as I type. You can change the trigger strings at will. The AHK code I use is `:*?:--qq::–` for n-dash and `:*?:--xx::—` for m-dash. If you want this and need help, let me know. I also use `e//` for `é`, `i''` for `ï`, etc. etc. I despise having to hold down shift/alt/control as much as using quotation marks as dead keys.

Comment: Thanks - saved for reference. Can't wait to try these out.

Comment: @Cerberus: For accents I got used to the alt+[key] thing...

Comment: @The Raven, good answer, but your powers of mind reading ("What the OP is wondering...") have quite failed you.  I'm familiar with use of an en-dash as a "super-hyphen," if you will, but that's not why I'd think to use it in this case.

Comment: In that case, the hyphen is correct. The only possible use of an en-dash in running text is as a "super-hyphen," as you put it, outside of its use as a marker for spans between numeric ranges. I generally follow the Chicago Manual of Style, but you don't have to.

Comment: 'It's taking me a very long time to master the formatting skills needed to do the kind of thing you just did.' and 'This is a very arcane bit of typesetting knowledge' lead me to query where 'correct / highest-end' becomes 'over-fastidious' or even silly.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a definitive single answer. The distinction between hyphens and en dashes has more to do with typesetting rules than usage.

In my experience, then, a hyphen is the sensible choice for uniting two words into a compound form. I don't actually have an en dash on my keyboard, and trying to signify one with a double dash makes matters worse. The word processing program you use may impose what it thinks is correct. I have not noticed what mine does.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a **slash** it might look even less ambiguous:

- Cost/Benefit

Comment: +1  Not bad (but not what I'll write).

Comment: @pilcrow: Why do you want either a dash or a hyphen? Just wondering.

Comment: It would be nice to receive an explanation on why I was down-voted.

Answer (score -1):

In general use, it should be a hyphen. An en dash is usually used more for joining two compound modifiers (personal cost–society benefit).

Comment: It's the other way around, actually. See my answer.