# What kind of dash character should I use at the end of a famous saying to mark of the author?

Tags: writing-style, dashes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Appropriate dash to use when attributing a quotation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28601/appropriate-dash-to-use-when-attributing-a-quotation)

What kind of dash character should I use at the end of a famous saying to mark of the author? Should I use "[en dash](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dash&a=*C.dash-_*Character.dflt-&a=*DPClash.CharacterE.dash-_*%7F8211-)" or the normal and shorter "[dash](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dash#)"? Or two "en dashes"?

> You are disoriented. Blackness swims toward you like a school of eels who have just seen something that eels like a lot. - Douglas Adams
>
> You are disoriented. Blackness swims toward you like a school of eels who have just seen something that eels like a lot. — Douglas Adams
>
> You are disoriented. Blackness swims toward you like a school of eels who have just seen something that eels like a lot. —— Douglas Adams