# What dash should be used for attribution of authorship?

Tags: dashes, em-dashes

Say I want to mention an author and their work, i.e. The Beatles—Abbey Road or Herman Melville—Moby Dick, which dash should go betwixt the two?

This question has been marked as a possible duplicate of [Appropriate dash to use when attributing a quotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28601/appropriate-dash-to-use-when-attributing-a-quotation) However, my question is very different as I want to attribute a work, not a quote. The dashes are used quite differently in the opposing scenarios.

What can be inferred from the other question is that em dashes are used for quote attribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the em (—) dash, based on my own personal preference and what I've seen used in the past.

I most commonly come across the en (–) dash, on the other hand, when it's used to represent a range of numbers. For example: *"Pages 204–238 were assigned from the textbook."*

But truly, this is a question of style. The recommended format for attributions will differ from guide to guide. *The Chicago Manual of Style* and the *Associated Press Stylebook* are two of the preeminent style guides for American English. I'd advise looking into both or their overseas equivalents if you'd like to learn more.

As a brief side note, "betwixt" is awfully archaic. If that's what you're going for, then great. But I'd highly suggest adopting "between" otherwise!

Comment: Haha, yes, I was aiming to sound archaic.