# What's the difference between - and -- in a phrase?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, dashes, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen)

When do I put a - in a sentence? Is it a more powerful comma? With a bigger pause?

Answer (score 0):

The dashes you described are known respectively as the *en-dash* and the *em-dash*. To describe the difference between their origins, [Mental Floss](http://www.mentalfloss.com/difference/en-dash-vs-em-dash/) writes:

> An en dash (–) is bigger than a hyphen but shorter than an em dash (—). Th e names come from an obscure typographical measurement system, but the dashes have now taken on a life of their own in grammar. The em dash is the spork of English grammar: It ain’t particularly pretty, but you can use it for most anything. **Em dashes can replace colons or sets of parentheses, or represent a sudden change in thought or tone.**

So when do you use an **en-dash**? Again from Mental Floss:

> 1. To show numerical ranges, signifying “up to and including”—of dates, ages, pages, etc. (Example: “I read pages 7–22 last night.”)
> 2. The storied “compound adjective hyphen,” an event so rare in the English language that proofreaders shiver with excitement whenever they come across it. Basically “pro-American” gets a regular hyphen because “American” is only one word, whereas “pro–Falkland Islands” gets an en dash because “Falkland Islands” is two words. So, too phrases like “Civil War–era.”

What about an **em-dash**? From [here](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/emdash.htm):

> Similar to an extended hyphen (-), an em dash is used to show a break in thought or a shift of tone.

If you'd like to read more about the differences between a hyphen (-), en-dash (–), and em-dash (—), see the blog post [here](http://cutewriting.blogspot.com/2008/06/en-dash-em-dash-and-hyphen.html) which summarizes the above.