# what's the difference between a hyphen, a dash and a minus sign?

Tags: hyphenation, dashes

hyphen(-), dash(—), minus(-)

What do I use when? and does it really matter? And what's their origin, why did people think they needed another very similar sign?

Comment: If you click on "tags" and fill in hyphen you find 300 posts on hyphen and 100 on dash.

Comment: Please look at other "hyphen" questions on this site, as rogermue suggested; also "en dash" and "em dash".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen)

Answer (score 1):

The minus and hyphen sign are the same thing.
A hyphen is a short, single-character line which connects word parts (i.e. ice-cream). A dash is a longer line—double the length of a hyphen—which indicates a break or an interruption in the thought. Dashes are used to set off part of a sentence. Unlike parentheses, which tend to minimize, dashes tend to emphasize the set-off text (i.e. There was only one person suited to the job—Mr. Lee).

I am not sure of their origin.

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/3/7/98/
http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/hyphens-and-dashes/

Comment: There are separate recommended used for the en dash (–) and the em dash (—).  I believe you were referring (correctly) to usage for the em dash.  Style guides vary as to usage of en dash.

Comment: oh, and by the way, "ice cream" is generally NOT hyphenated in AmE, except perhaps when used as a modifier (**e.g.** "ice-cream sandwich").

Comment: For competent printers, the hyphen: - ,  the minus sign: − , the short dash: – , and the long dash: — , are four different things, although the short dash and the minus sign are awfully close, and the two dashes are to some extent interchangeable.

Comment: @WAS minus and hyphen are not the same, hyphen used between words to connect them but minus is an operator used for subtraction and applicable on numbers only.
Yes, the character used in computers and typewriters could be the same for both.