# Hyphens with "vs." and "versus"... with time frames as well, such as a.m. and p.m

Tags: punctuation

Are hyphens needed on each side of "vs." and "versus" below?

And are hyphens required/needed on each side of "to" with the phrasal adjective involving time in the last example? They are phrasal adjectives that probably need them, correct?

**the Mike Tyson-vs.-Evander Holyfield pay-per-view**

the Rousey-versus-Holm fight

the Rousey-vs.-Holm fight

the 11 p.m.-to-7 a.m. shift

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Examples at [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/HyphensEnDashesEmDashes.html?page=9) say no hyphen at least in your time range example.

> If you want to use **from** with 9–5, make the **to** explicit: We work **from 9 to 5**. Otherwise omit from: We work **9–5**.

Even if strictly okay from grammar perspective, as described at [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/stacked-modifiers) such heavily stacked modifiers as you quote in the examples do look unwieldy.

Perhaps, you could trim the **vs** and **to** from your examples and use **[en dash](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2126/131620)**,  e.g.

> the Mike Tyson–Evander Holyfield pay-per-view
>   the Rousey–Holm fight
>   the 23:00–7:00 shift

Interesting **en dash** article at [thepunctuationguide.com](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html).