# How is a dash used in English

Tags: dashes

Is a dash used between words in word combinations like fill up?  Or is it fill-up?

Comment: A dash is a long line used as a punctuation mark—here is an example. A shorter dash (called the "en dash") may be used to write ranges of numbers, like 5–10. "Fill-up" doesn't contain a dash, but a hyphen. You would use the hyphenated spelling "fill-up" if you are using it as a noun, and the spaced spelling "fill up" if you are using it as a verb. See the following question for more details.

Comment: For more information on the use of dashes, see [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116)